# How can I combine two objects of different subclasses into a third subclass?

Tags: java, inheritance

Something like this:

```
public class Type
{
  //code
}

public class TypeA extends Type
{
  //code
}

public class TypeB extends Type
{
  //code
}
```

I want to create a third class named Type C that includes all values of both Type A and B.

For example, lets say that both Type A and B have two values and I want to make something like this in the main class:

```
Type c = new TypeC(TypeA(value, value), TypeB(value, value));
```

Comment: We would have to write `... new TypeC(new TypeA(...), new TypeB(...))`. --- We can define a constructor `public TypeC(TypeA typeA, TypeB typeB) { ... }` on class `TypeC`.

Comment: oh this was more obvious than I thought Thank you so much!!